How to Handle Concurrency in a Node.js Server with Long-Running Tasks and Asynchronous File Reading?
I'm developing a simple Node.js web server and I'm having some trouble handling concurrent requests. My server needs to perform the following tasks:

Serve a welcome message at the root URL (/).

Perform a long-running computation without blocking other requests at the URL (/long-task).

Read and return the contents of a file asynchronously at the URL (/read-file).

Handle 404 errors for unknown routes.


Requirements:

The server should handle multiple requests concurrently without blocking the main thread.

Use asynchronous APIs provided by Node.js to achieve non-blocking I/O operations.

Properly handle errors and edge cases (e.g., file not found, server errors).
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
// Function to simulate a long-running task
function longRunningTask(callback) {
setTimeout(() => {
callback('Long-running task completed');
}, 3000); // Simulate a task that takes 3 seconds
}
// Function to read a file asynchronously
function readFileAsync(filePath, callback) {
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
if (err) {
callback(err);
} else {
callback(null, data);
}
});
}
// Create an HTTP server
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
if (req.url === '/') {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Hello, world!\n');
} else if (req.url === '/long-task') {
longRunningTask((message) => {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end(message + '\n');
});
} else if (req.url === '/read-file') {
readFileAsync('example.txt', (err, data) => {
if (err) {
res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Error reading file\n');
} else {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end(data);
}
});
} else {
res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Not Found\n');
}
});
// Start the server
server.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});



Which specific issue you are facing?During the code execution what error or bug you have encountered.

Please format your code properly.

Use http.createServer to set up routes for handling different requests asynchronously. You can handle long tasks by using process.nextick() to avoid blocking other requests.Also use res.end('404 Not Found') for 404 errors!

For initial development and handling the task you can refer :-
https://habtesoft.medium.com/how-does-node-js-handle-concurrency-and-scalability-de4d0005fd6
if you want to fine tune the NodeJs concurrency and Cluster point you can follow :-
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency
Remember Node concurrency Has overhead while handling Do not use to create for  CPU intensive task . Follow below Suggestion
https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-multithreading-worker-threads-pros-cons/
As question is not specific i have provided General referene.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


You can utilize event loops here, handle long tasks by using
process.nextick() to avoid blocking other async tasks.

Also use res.end('404 Not Found') for 404 errors!
You can use this code to implement your /read-file functionality
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

app.get('/read-file', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'example.txt'); // Change 'example.txt' to your file name
    
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
});

